# Can't update flatpak: »Flatpak system operation Deploy not allowed for user«

Tags: 19.04, policykit, flatpak

I have some problems trying to update my flatpaks. I have several applications installed via flatpak (system wide) and from time to time I am updating all of them with the command:

```
flatpak update -y
```

This used to work very well, but al of the sudden I get the error:

```
Flatpak system operation Deploy not allowed for user
```

Here a complete example:

```
user:~$ flatpak update -y
Looking for updates…


        ID                                                          Arch   Zweig Remote  Download
 1. [✗] org.kde.WaylandDecoration.QGnomePlatform-decoration         x86_64 5.12  flathub 1.0 kB / 56,8 kB
 2. [✗] org.kde.WaylandDecoration.QGnomePlatform_decoration.Sources x86_64 5.12  flathub 1.0 kB / 52,6 kB

Warning: Flatpak system operation Deploy not allowed for user
Warning: Flatpak system operation Deploy not allowed for user
Installation complete.
```

This might be a problem with policykit, the which – as the flatpaks are installed system wide – should have asked me for an administrator password during the update process, but failed to do so.

Can anybody please hint me in the right direction how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run `flatpak` with `sudo`, as in

```
sudo flatpak update -y
```

Another possible workaround is to use `setsid`:

```
setsid flatpak update -y
```

This runs the program in a different session and solved for me a similar problem with the `grsync` tool.